# How to generate invoice number with special requirement using PHP or MySql

Tags: php, mysql

how to generate invoice number such as below :

```
Invoice Number = MC1200001 

MC : Company name
12 : current year (Flexibel)
00001 : auto increment (Flexibel - auto increment and will reset to 00001 again if year is 2013)
```

expected result :

```
current year 2012 :

MC1200001
MC1200002
MC1200003
.....

year 2013

MC1300001
MC1300002
MC1300003
.....
```

Need your idea or solution for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: So what did you try? Can you make a string starting with `MC`? And can you find the current date or not? Did you google how to find a date? Is the auto-increment a problem? Is the reset a problem?

Comment: for me reset problem ,my previous invoice number just simple auto-increment using mysql

Comment: What storage engine are you using?

Comment: im using mysql 5.1 .. (sorry php and mysql still new to me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use three columns to express the different parts of the number and use a view or simple CONCAT expression to grab the entire number per invoice.

Then to get a new number, you'd insert a record using a function that would return the actual row id or concatenated number.

I'd do something like this: (leaving the leading zero's out for brevity)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS invoces;

CREATE TABLE invoices (
   id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT
  ,company CHAR(2)
  ,number INT
  ,fiscal_year INT
 , PRIMARY KEY (company, number, fiscal_year)
);

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS spCreateInvoice;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE spCreateInvoice
(
   pCompany CHAR(2)
  ,pFiscalYear INT
)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO invoices (
    company, fiscal_year, number
  ) SELECT
        pCompany
      , pFiscalYear
      , 1+MAX(number) 
    FROM invoices 
    WHERE 
        fiscal_year=pFiscalYear;

  SET @id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

  SELECT CONCAT(i.company, i.number, i.fiscal_year) invoice_number, i.* from invoices i WHERE id = @id;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL spCreateInvoice('MC', 12);
CALL spCreateInvoice('MC', 12);
CALL spCreateInvoice('MC', 12);
CALL spCreateInvoice('MC', 12);

CALL spCreateInvoice('MC', 13);
CALL spCreateInvoice('MC', 13);
CALL spCreateInvoice('MC', 13);
CALL spCreateInvoice('MC', 13);
```

You can run this as a script against your mysql test database and see the following output:

```
invoice_number  id  company number  fiscal_year
MC012           1   MC      0       12

invoice_number  id  company number  fiscal_year
MC112           2   MC      1       12

invoice_number  id  company number  fiscal_year
MC212           3   MC      2       12

invoice_number  id  company number  fiscal_year
MC312           4   MC      3       12

invoice_number  id  company number  fiscal_year
MC013           5   MC      0       13

invoice_number  id  company number  fiscal_year
MC113           6   MC      1       13

invoice_number  id  company number  fiscal_year
MC213           7   MC      2       13

invoice_number  id  company number  fiscal_year
MC313           8   MC          3   13
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// after save to database 
$invoiceCode = 'My Company Logo'.date("y").mysql_insert_id() ;
?>
```

Comment: thanks "// after save to database " will solve my probelm for auto-increment id but now only how to reset..

Comment: Although your answer is simple, but it is not practical.
It is prone for race condition, thus the accepted answer is best fit for this question because it uses transaction

Answer (score 1):

try this..

$compcode = "MC";
$result = $compcode.date('y').str_pad($runningnumber, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

Answer (score -2):

Yes, below is my final solution and its working :

```
<?php
@mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Database error!');
echo "mysql_connect : Connected!</br>";   // if connected show 'Connected!'
echo '</br>';
mysql_select_db("invoice") or die('could not select');

$result4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `order` ORDER BY id desc") or die('could not select');   //Select last transaction
$row4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4);

$invoice4 = $row4['invoice_number'];
$inc_number = $row4['inc_number'];
$year = $row4['year'];

//Setting Invoice Format
$brand = 'GB';
$cur_date = date('y');  // date('y')
$invoice = $brand.$cur_date.'00001';
$customer_id = rand(5487 , 9854);

if($cur_date == $year) {   //if current year equal to last year in transaction 

    if($invoice4 == $invoice && $inc_number == '1') {
        //IF EXIST 

        //add inc_number 
        $inc_number_add = $inc_number + 1; // Increment by 1

        //invoice_number
        $inc = str_pad($inc_number_add, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); //Format with leading 0 eg: 00001
        $invoice_number_db = $brand.$cur_date.$inc;

        //create new order
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `order` (customer_id,invoice_number,inc_number,year) VALUES ($customer_id, '$invoice_number_db' ,$inc_number_add,$cur_date)") 
        or die('Cannot Insert into database!');
        echo "<br/>Insert Success!</br>";

    }
    else {
        //IF NOT EXIST 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `order` (customer_id,year) VALUES ($customer_id,$cur_date)") or die('Cannot Insert into database!');
            echo "Insert customer_id Success!";

            echo '</br>';

            // Retrieve data again after create
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE customer_id='$customer_id'") or die('could not select');
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            //var
            $id_val = $row['id'];
            $inc_number_add = $inc_number + 1;  // Increment by 1
            $inc = str_pad($inc_number_add, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); //Format with leading 0 eg: 00001
            $invoice = $brand.$cur_date.$inc;

            //Update invoice
            mysql_query("UPDATE `order` SET invoice_number='$invoice' , inc_number='$inc_number_add' WHERE customer_id=$customer_id") or die('error 89');
            echo "</br>UPDATE invoice_number Success!</br>";
    }

}
    else {

        //IF TODAY IS NEW YEAR RESET INVOICE NUMBER
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `order` (customer_id,invoice_number,inc_number,year) VALUES ($customer_id, '$invoice' , '1' ,$cur_date)") 
        or die('Cannot Insert into database!');
        echo "<br/>Insert customer_id Success!</br>";

    }

        echo "<br/><br/>FINAL OUTPUT <br/>";
        $result_3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE customer_id='$customer_id' ") or die('could not select');
            $row_3 = mysql_fetch_array($result_3);

            $id3 = $row_3['id'];
            $customer_id3 = $row_3['customer_id'];
            $inc_number = $row_3['inc_number'];
            $invoice3 = $row_3['invoice_number'];

            echo 'id '.$id3.' - ';
            echo 'customer_id '.$customer_id3.' - ';
            echo 'inc_number '.$inc_number.' - ';
            echo 'invoice '.$invoice3. '<br/>';

?>
```

Comment: -1: please be aware that 1: you're using `mysql_connect` wrong and 2: it is scheduled to be removed from php in a future version. the interface you're using and the way you're using it (with the anonymous global connection) is very widely considered bad practice and rightfully so. You should really look into http://php.net/pdo